# Do blockades in star wars make sense?

Tags: star-wars, spaceship

So this is something I never understood in the franchise, is it in the original trilogy or the prequels. They are times where the heroes encounter blockades from enemy forces that are meant to prevent ships from leaving the planet's orbit. So far so good. But how can you blockade a whole planet?

You must at least have thousands of ships and there would be still thousand of square kilometers to pass through. And the heroes **Always** go through the one spot where enemies are waiting for them.

Here are good examples:

the escape from Naboo in Episode 1:
[image]

As you can see, there is plenty of space above and under the blockade, Also I dont believe they build an asteroid ring of ships here.

Here is the same thing in Hoth:

[image]

It is also worth noting, that the trade federation is **not** the empire and would not have that much resources to begin with.

So why is this a reasonable thing to do?

Comment: well the problem stands, how is the whole ring around the plane covered ? How does the trade federation do that ?why not fly above it and then use hyperdrive

Comment: I addressed that point threefold in my answer, I believe. First, only a few discrete hyperspace lanes need be blocked. Second, any ship must get fairly far away from a planet’s mass shadow before jumping at all. Third, there are long-range weapons and swarms of TIE fighters and other smaller ships.

Comment: And most important, does Star Wars make sense at all?

Comment: @Julian are you questioning you arguments about ancient space wizards ????

Comment: @Meerkat Our ancient omniimpotent spacewizards can achieve anything. And if shockwaves of explosions happen in ring form, a ring blockade is even more effective. But would that mean, that if the blockaded planet would be destroid, the explosion would happen in the same plane as the blockade?

Comment: @Julian obviously your not a physicist. You have to calculate how many wookies live on the planet we are looking at. If the population is at least 10 % wookies then the tilt goes up 2,55 degrees. Next we would have to messure the medichlorean counter and figure out, why these even exit in the first place. After we asked George lucas that you would have you answer delivered to you in a star wars collectors edition box set for only 119 $